# Sorting biblatex bibliography by last name beginning with "Al-"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, ieee-style

I would like to sort my biblatex bibliography by last name. Unfortunately, names beginning with "Al-" are not sorted as expected.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Bib-File:**

```
@article{A,
title = {Title-A},
volume = {1},
journaltitle = {Journal},
date = {2000},
pages = {1-2},
author = {Abc, FirstName},
}

@article{B,
title = {Title-B},
volume = {1},
journaltitle = {Journal},
date = {2000},
pages = {1-2},
author = {Al-Xyz, FirstName},
}

@article{C,
title = {Title-C},
volume = {1},
journaltitle = {Journal},
date = {2000},
pages = {1-2},
author = {OtherAuthor, FirstName},
}

@article{D,
title = {Title-D},
volume = {1},
journaltitle = {Journal},
date = {2000},
pages = {1-2},
author = {Xyz, FirstName}
}
```

The expected order would be the same as in the bib file (Al-Xyz before OtherAuthor), but what I get is:

```
References
[1] F. Abc, “Title-a,” Journal, vol. 1, pp. 1–2, 2000.
[2] F. OtherAuthor, “Title-c,” Journal, vol. 1, pp. 1–2, 2000.
[3] F. Al-Xyz, “Title-b,” Journal, vol. 1, pp. 1–2, 2000.
[4] F. Xyz, “Title-d,” Journal, vol. 1, pp. 1–2, 2000.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` or rather Biber strips the Arabic name prefix "al-" and other two-letter prefixes with hyphen before sorting. This is documented in §4.5.9 *Fine Tuning Sorting* on p. 209 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). The relevant macro is called `\DeclareNosort` and its default value is

```
\DeclareNosort{
  % strip prefixes like 'al-' when sorting names
  \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{\A\p{L}{2}\p{Pd}}}
  % strip some diacritics when sorting names
  \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}
```

You can turn off this behaviour with

```
\DeclareNosort{
  % strip some diacritics when sorting names
  \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{[\x{2bf}\x{2018}]}}
}
```

Now only the two diacritics `ʿ` and `‘` are ignored.

[image]

It turns out the explanation in the manual for version 3.11 is slightly outdated. This has been corrected in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/811878bcb2f0632b7afad43562b4c8f5415cb345 and the answer here already uses the new and correct terminology.